# Unknown returned type in PostgreSQL query

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, type-conversion

The following query works:

```
SELECT a, b
FROM unnest(ARRAY[(1,2), (3,4)])
AS t(a integer, b integer);

a b
_ _
1 2
3 2
```

However, I wasn't able to use a different column type such as `varchar(255)`:

```
SELECT a, b
FROM unnest(ARRAY[(1,'hello'), (3,'world')])
AS t(a integer, b varchar(255));

ERROR:  42804: function return row and query-specified return row do not match
DETAIL:  Returned type unkown at ordinal position 2, but query expects text.
```

It seems that, in the second case, the column type is inferred as `unknown`, which is not cast to `varchar(255)` automatically.

How do I make the second example work and return columns with the right type, if possible without warnings and without modifying the `ARRAY[...]` definition?

*Background: I am trying to improve performance of large bulk insert operations using the `psycopg2` Python module, which does not support using multiple rows in `VALUES` arguments. I stumbled onto the above example while trying out some other methods.*

Comment: I'm not sure why you state that psycopg2 doesn't support multiple rows in `VALUES`. The following works just fine for me: `cur.execute('INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s, %s), (%s, %s), (%s, %s)', (1, 'foo', 2, 'bar', 3, 'baz'))`

Comment: What I mean is that it doesn't support an arbitrary number of rows, e.g. something like `cur.execute('INSERT INTO too VALUES %s', (list_of_rows,))` doesn't exist.

Comment: Ahh, and you're hoping to substitute the array as a single parameter, I see.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this without generating a warning by creating a type and casting the records to it:

```
create type t as (a integer, b varchar(255));

select * from unnest(array[(1,'hello'), (3,'world')]::t[]);
┌───┬───────┐
│ a │   b   │
├───┼───────┤
│ 1 │ hello │
│ 3 │ world │
└───┴───────┘
```

<sub>tested on 9.4 and 9.3 (db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=c362d6405b34dd364827e4c10a031958))</sub>

Answer (score 7):

It is ugly, but you can try:

```
SELECT a, b::text
FROM unnest(ARRAY[(1,'hello'), (3,'world')])
AS t(a integer, b unknown);
```

This way the type defined in `AS` matches the output of `unnest()`, which you can cast to your needs in the `SELECT` list.

You can try  this in a small [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cf9d3/2).

Answer (score 2):

Should do it:

```
SELECT a, b
FROM unnest(ARRAY[(1,varchar 'hello'), (3,varchar 'world')])
AS t(a integer, b varchar(255));
```

Comment: This works, however I wasn't able to force `psycopg2` to include type casts inside the `ARRAY[...]` definition. Is it possible to do it without? I edited my question to reflect that.